# Find the values of K so the following series is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to find the values of K in this series so the function is convergent

series of one to infinity of

\begin{equation*}
\frac{30^n(n!)^3}{(kn)!}
\end{equation*}

I did the ratio test and ended up:

with the limit as $n\to \infty$ of \begin{equation*}
\frac{30(kn)!(n+1)^3}{(k(n+1))!}
\end{equation*}

Comment: If you use the ratio test correctly, you should get something different. Try doing again your computations.

Comment: @Crostul thank you, see updated answer. is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by taking the ratio test and expanding the factorials:

$$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|= \frac{30(n+1)^3}{\prod_{i=1}^k(kn+i)} \to l<1$$

How does this help us compute which values of $k$ make the series converge?

Comment: Not yet, you have $\frac{(k(n+1))!}{(kn)!}=$...

Comment: Yes, sorry again. What I meant was, try to expand that fraction as a product $\prod$ to see what is going on.

Comment: so is my function correct tho? or was it correct previously

Comment: Yes, your ratio is correct. Try to evaluate now what values of k would ensure that ratio has a limit $l<1$ by expanding it as a product. Use, for example, with $k=2$ to get a feel for it.

Comment: yea which one was correct, cuz i changed it into two different ones, top or bottom

Comment: Top (although a bracket is misplaced).

Comment: thank you very much! but the top has n^3 and on the bottom n^1 so wouldn't it always be divergent?

Comment: All I did was rewrite the factorials, see if that helps.

Comment: sorry this is late, but thanks! I got it with your help

Comment: Great! If you can, tell me your result afterwards :)